# How to configure vpn on Elementary OS Loki?

Tags: release-loki, openvpn

I am running an Elementary OS Loki stable build and confirmed that
openvpn is present in my system.

However I'd like a comprehensive guide to configuring VPN for privacy on my network connection.

Thank you.

Comment: Who is your VPN service through?

Comment: I am using openvpn

Comment: openvpn is a client, and can be used to create a server (although you would need a remote server for that setup to be useful), have you purchased access to a VPN server? This question needs more clarification. You can't just start using a VPN, unless you a) pay for one, b) provide one yourself or c) use a free / non-commercial one... VPNs are trust networks though, and so I would be wary of people offering to tunnel your traffic for free.

Comment: When I go to the VPN settings it doesn't give me that + option it just says "No VPN Connections. Add a new VPN connection to begin." it doesn't give me that + button in the VPN settings...

Answer (score 4):

So when Pretzel Jones asked who your provider was, he was asking whose VPN are you looking to connect to. Examples might include NordVPN, PrivateInternetAccess and Mullvad, just to name a few.

These services will then provide you with certificates and credentials you can install on your system through OpenVPN that you then connect to once you're online (ie connected to a network by wifi or otherwise).

The procedure there, typically involves downloading an .ovpn file (once you have an active subscription which will usually involve paying for the service) and IMPORTING that configuration file by:

- clicking your network manager icon (usually a wifi symbol if you're already online)
- selecting "Network Settings"
- selecting "VPN" in the left hand menu under "Virtual"
- clicking the "+" icon
- selecting "Import a saved configuration file"
- browsing to your .ovpn file
- hit "Create"
- Fill in your account info and point network-manager to your certificate files and key files
- Hit save and connect from the network manager icon drop down menu

[This guide from NordVPN](https://support.nordvpn.com/hc/en-us/articles/206927749-Linux-Ubuntu-14-04-setup)  is a good reference!

Let me know if you have more specific questions as you move through this process and I can update my answer!

Some providers do have applications you can install to connect to their service that have some neat features like disable internet if the VPN connection drops.

Good luck!

Comment: You can also have it auto connect to a vpn connection on certain wifi networks. You can configure this in the Network settings > Wireless > Settings > General. Enable "Automatically connect to VPN when using this connection" and select a vpn connection.